# Asymptotic time complexity

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

after reading many articles or answers I still can't solve a problem of determining the asymptotic time complexity o a function. The function is for example like this:

```
def function(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(n):
                for k in range(10000):
                    print("output")
```

What will be the asymptotic time complexity due to n and how many times will be written "output" due to n?

Thank you.

Comment: Make some experiments for small vales of n. That will most likely give you an idea.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015). The analysis that needs to be done here to determine how many times is each line executed is fairly simple (even if it's easy to get misled by the nested loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Theory

In this example, the time complexity should be `O(n)` even though there are 3 nested loops.

- The `i` loop runs n times.
- The `j` loop runs n times, but only if `i` is 0.
- The `k` loop runs 10000 times, but it is a constant factor.

To better explain what happens, let's distinguish between `n_i`, `n_j` even though they're both equal to `n`. The complexity is :

`O(1 * n_j * 10000 + n_i * 1) = O(10000 * n_j + n_i) = O(n_j + n_i) = O(n + n) = O(n)`

Output should be printed `10000 * n` times.

## Check with %timeit

If you replace the `print` call by a counter increment:

```
def function(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(n):
                for k in range(10000):
                    count += 1
```

you can call `%timeit` in IPython with increasing values of `n`:

```
%timeit function(10)
5.01 ms ± 36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit function(100)
50.4 ms ± 334 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit function(1000)
497 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit function(10000)
5.03 s ± 27.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Times seem to match `O(n)` perfectly!

## Variations

The complexity would be `O(n**2)` without the `if`:

```
def function(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(10000):
                print("output")
```

The complexity would be `O(n**3)` if `k` is in `range(n)`:

```
def function(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(n):
                print("output")
```